# Unable to deploy artifact using encrypted password with LDAP enabled

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory

We are using Artifactory Version 4.7.0. I have configured LDAP for Artifactory and i am able to login successfully. When i am trying to use encrypted password for deploying artifacts, it's not working. In Artifacts tab, i clicked on "Set Me Up" and generated Maven settings after entering my credentials. I then downloaded the settings.xml file which had the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:9090/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:9090/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:9090/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://artifactory:9090/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Then i went to my profile, entered password and copied the Encrypted Password as shown below:

[image]

I copied this password in my settings.xml as shown below:

```
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP6FcvsVawZhcfEdZB2PCTrCUZa"}</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>${security.getCurrentUsername()}</username>  
      <password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"AP6FcvsVawZhcfEdZB2PCTrCUZa"}</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
```

and then when i tried deploying an artifact, i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project more-maven-examples: Failed to deploy artifac
ts: Could not transfer artifact com.infiniteskills.maven:more-maven-examples:jar:1.0 from/to central (http://artifactory:9090/libs-release-local):
Failed to transfer file: http://artifactory:9090/libs-release-local/com/infiniteskills/maven/more-maven-examples/1.0/more-maven-examples-1.0.jar. R
eturn code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Entry in *request.log* file for the failed attempt:

```
20160525143037|9526|REQUEST|10.20.55.124|non_authenticated_user|PUT|/libs-release-local/com/infiniteskills/maven/more-maven-examples/1.0/more-maven-examples-1.0.jar|HTTP/1.1|401|2981
20160525143037|2|REQUEST|10.20.55.124|non_authenticated_user|PUT|/libs-release-local/com/infiniteskills/maven/more-maven-examples/1.0/more-maven-examples-1.0.pom|HTTP/1.1|401|1235
```

In Security > General > Password Encryption Policy is set to SUPPORTED. Also, Passwords Encryption is set to encrypted.

Surprisingly, when i *hard-code* my name and LDAP password in the settings.xml file in the same `<server>` block, it works fine.

Am i doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: Maybe you need to drop the quotes around the password...?

Comment: Thanks. Tried your suggestion but didn't work. :( Same error.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on Artifactory 4.5.0, when attempting to use the feature for Ivy instead of Maven. Have you found any solution/explanation?

Comment: Not yet. The [JIRA](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-10354) is yet to be assigned.

Comment: @Technext I am using 4.13 and have the same bug. I tried to hard-code my user and password, but I can't use it. How did you do? clear password?

Comment: @malaguna: I used what carlspring suggested in his answer below because there was no other working alternative.

Comment: Broken yet again in 5.10.3

Answer (score 5):

Replace the entire line with your credentials

```
<username>actual-username-here</username>  
<password>your-encrypted-password-here</password>
```

Tried it now. works a treat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i've switched job. Can't test it, at least now. :)

Comment: I was getting `401: Unauthorized` when I used my encrypted password. I had to use the `API Key` for the password.

Answer (score 2):

You `<password/>` section should be something like:

```
<password>{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}</password>
```

Have a look at the [Maven Encryption Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I was actually skeptical whether it will work. It's because Maven is automatically generating a line (`<password>${security.getEscapedEncryptedPassword()!"*** Insert encrypted password here ***"}</password>`) for the encrypted password when i download the settings.xml from Artifactory. It seems what you suggested was present in old version of Artifactory although i never used that feature at that point of time. Looks like Artifactory has changed how the encrypted password is handled (as visible in its current form).

Comment: That is not generated by maven it's generated by Artifactory.

Comment: Sorry, i meant Artifactory only :)

Comment: Do you have a `${user.home}/.m2/settings-security.xml`? If I were you, Id just really follow the link I gave you. It works for sure. Do it yourself...

Comment: We don't use `${user.home}/.m2/settings-security.xml` although i today tried the link you gave. It works but my concern is that encryption should work with LDAP credentials.

Comment: @Technext: But these ___are___ the same credentials, they are just hashed.

Comment: You're right. I thought so too but seems while trying out scenarios, i switched between internal and LDAP password and that's when something went wrong. I removed the user and logged in again. Then when i tried using my LDAP password for generating the hash, it worked. :) Thanks.

Comment: However, what do you think might be the motivation behind generating password at Artifactory's end in the version that i am using (4.7.0)? I feel it might have to do with 'doing away with' this activity of generating two passwords at user's end (one for `settings-security.xml` and another for `settings.xml`). I feel this is still a bug in the 4.7.0 version. I yesterday downloaded the latest version i.e., 4.8.0 and the issue persists.

Comment: I understand very well what your motivation is, but from what I can tell, it's either broken, or being misused. I think you should file a bug with JFrog.

Comment: I have filed a bug. Let's see.

Comment: @Technext - has your bug received any attention? The settings.xml generation with encrypted password still appears to be broken in Artifactory OSS 5.1.4.

Comment: @MikePartridge: Seems no one from Artifactory has looked into it. It's still [unassigned](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-10354)

Comment: They finally fixed this on the latest release (5.3.0 - 11th of May): [RTFACT-13419] - When using "Set Me Up" for maven the insert credentials doesn't work

Comment: And it's broken again.